# What's the meaning of "if only"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Kantorovich kept pondering the question while he was on summer vacation with his new bride. He soon realized this was a generalizable problem: there could be many other managerial and engineering applications **if only** he could find a way to solve it.

[Source](https://dokumen.pub/economists-at-war-how-a-handful-of-economists-helped-win-and-lose-the-world-wars-0198846002-9780198846000.html)

---

What's the meaning of "**if only**"?

Comment: **If only** has several meanings - have you tried searching **if only meaning**? Here, the sense is that he would very much like to solve the problem because it would be useful in so many ways.

Comment: To some extent you could think of ***only*** here as an "intensifier" for preceding ***if***. But actually, of course, it's just carrying its normal *literal* meaning. Kantorovich doesn't want ***lots*** of things - the ***one and only thing he desperately wants*** is to find a way to solve whatever "the question" is that's been preoccupying him.

Comment: Please see [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/if%20only): **if only** idiom — used to talk about something that one wants to happen or be true.

Comment: @WeatherVane Examples of the Merriam-Webster entry for "if only" don't have the main clauses. So I'm not sure if it really fits the use of "**if only**" in my post.

Comment: Let me add a fuller example: I could go shopping if only it would stop raining.

Answer (score 2):

**If only** has the combined meaning of **if** and **only**. "If" implies a condition, and "only" implies just one thing. To consider the example given, compare these sentences:

"*There could be many applications possible if he could solve the problem*." Here solving the problem is the condition, and obviously the vital condition; but it may not be the only condition. Maybe he also needs more funding, but that's not the key focus at this point.

"*There could be many applications possible if only he could solve the problem*." This sentence, with "only" added, suggests that solving the problem is indeed the only condition that needs to be met. All other conditions are already resolved.

Answer (score 2):

'If only' means, the possibility of a **single** occurrence. If used with 2 clauses, then it also means that under a single condition, another event will follow it.

> If only there were more matches, I would stay warm.

This is the 2 clause form of 'if only'. It is stating that under the event that there are more matches, the person will be warm.

> If only he could get better and we could all be happy again

This is another 2 clause form of if only. Under the condition that 'he' gets better, only then will they be happy.

Here are some phrases where if only is used to describe peoples desires or wishes.

> If only they would just leave it alone.

> Imagine if only ten people finished this book?

> If only it were just in cinemas!

> If only the good vibes lasted.

These are all one clause, this implies that someone wishes for something to happen.

Answer (score 1):

It can have several meanings.

In this particular case, it is expressing a wish.